# Increment column before response download - Laravel

Tags: laravel, download, response, insert-update

I want to simply increment a column for each download but it adds 2 or more instead of 1. Here is my code:

```
 public function download(Music $music)
{ 

    $music->increment('downloads');


    $file=$music->getFilePath();
    return response()->download($file,$music->title);
}
```

However, if I remove response()->download... line it works correctly. What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: are you calling $music->save() after you're done?

Comment: No I don't save the music, I just update it by calling increment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if the download function is being called multiple times, not just once.
- Implement response download function by yourself.

[update]

IDM issue. Can be solved by separating increment and download routes.

Comment: I'm sure the function is being called multiple times when use response->download(), but it works fine when I remove the download command.

Comment: If you are using a download manager, then it might call your route multiple times behind the scene for different reasons. Test that !

Comment: Woow! you're right IDM is the reason of the issue. thanks, but is there any solution for this problem? As we know that the most of the users use IDM !

Comment: You can create a session for each download and you can expire it once you the request has been made. But that's a long hard work. I suggest that you separate your downloading url to the increment route. So when IDM calls the route repeatedly it won't increment.

Comment: And can you check my response as an answer please.

Comment: @hagere can you show us how to call the increament route after successful response?